# Can I decompile project with keystore?

Tags: android, decompiler

Lost my usb which is having my android project.
I just tested that application so I only have that apk.
Can I extract apk to project...?

Comment: Tip: use a cloud solution to save your development files. Me personally have my workspace in my Dropbox folder, so it's syncing my development files in real time. Even if my computer caught fire, they would still be saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

For this purpose first of all you decompile this apk into source code for decompiling the apk following purpose is used

Step 1:

Make a new folder and copy over the .apk file that you want to decode.

Now rename the extension of this .apk file to .zip (e.g. rename from filename.apk to filename.zip) and save it. Now you can access the classes.dex files, etc. At this stage you are able to see drawables but not xml and java files, so continue.

Step 2:

Now extract this .zip file in the same folder (or NEW FOLDER).

Download [dex2jar](https://code.google.com/p/dex2jar/downloads/detail?name=dex2jar-0.0.9.15.zip&can=2&q=)  and extract it to the same folder (or NEW FOLDER).

Move the classes.dex file into the dex2jar folder.

Now open command prompt and change directory to that folder (or NEW FOLDER). Then write d2j-dex2jar classes.dex and press enter. You now have the classes_dex2jar.jar file in the same folder.

Download [java decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/), double click on jd-gui, click on open file, and open classes.dex.dex2jar file from that folder: now you get class files.

Save all of these class files (In jd-gui, click File -> Save All Sources) by src name. At this stage you get the java source but the .xml files are still unreadable, so continue.

Step 3:

Now open another new folder

Put in the .apk file which you want to decode

Download the latest version of [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool1.5.2.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)%20AND%20apktool%20install%20window%20(https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/downloads/detail?name=apktool-install-windows-r05-ibot.tar.bz2&can=2&q=)  (both can be downloaded from the same link) and place them in the same folder

Download framework-res.apk and put it in the same folder (Not all apk file need this file, but it doesn't hurt)

Open a command window

Navigate to the root directory of APKtool and type the following command: apktool if framework-res.apk

apktool d myApp.apk (where myApp.apk denotes the filename that you want to decode)

now you get a file folder in that folder and can easily read the apk's xml files.

Step 4:

It's not any step just copy contents of both folder(in this case both new folder)to the single one

and update the source code...